# Initializing StateNotifier Provider to return list of products to a feeds screen

Tags: state, e-commerce, riverpod

I have tried several suggestions and rewritten my code to get past errors. But now only a blank screen (no list of products) being returned on navigation. Here are screenshots of the 2 critical screens (the productController and the feeds screen.

[image: ProductController]

[image: FeedsScreen]

[image: FeedScreen showing blank slate with no products returned]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Juan Carlos for reminding me that StateNotifier keeps app state. After a restful and second reflection, I changed products to state in my getter statement and keeping the original code. Everything now works as expected. I am ready to implement API data fetch from Firestore now that the static hardcoded data acts as expected. It served its purpose as a placeholder. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of a `StateNotifier` is to hold a state, so in your super constructor you are using a empty array if state (optional positional parameter of ProductNotifier) is null.

You are not assigning your products to the state.

As your products are hardcode, you can either pass them as the initial state:

[image]

```dart
...
  (ref) => ProductNotifier(products); // products is your List<Product>
...
```

or

[image]

```dart
class ProductNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Product>> {

ProductNotifier() : super(products); // products is your List<Product>

...
```

Comment: Thanks. Both of the suggested solutions gave errors. First one (initializing the ProductNotifier with my array of products gave "undefined name products" since the name use occurs outside of the class and unable to define the getter there. The second option of including it in the super () results in "<List<Product>> can't be assigned to type list Product". Probably because the product model doesn't reconcile with this. Flutter does not allow a return type to be added to a constructor so I am stuck. Any further thoughts? Thanks a million.